# When it comes to privileges management, is Active Directory still a match against Node.js modules?

Tags: node.js, database, active-directory, ldap, passport.js

I am currently working on a web app that will have to handle users and user privileges (like in most web projects). I intend to develop it around Node.js which seems to solve most of my constraints. But I have been advised to use an "Active Directory"-like structure for privileges management and query it using LDAP.

So I'm wondering, **is it still relevant nowadays to use an "Active Directory"-like structure to authenticate users/handle privileges ?** Node seems to have enough to offer regarding that aspect (I'm thinking of *Passport*) with a storage of the Users and their privileges in a database.

In my data model, I know that I will have to deal with Users, that belong to Departments. These departments have Projects, that Users can belong to (multiple or none). I thought a relational or a non-relational database was going to be the perfect match, but now I hesitate.

Thank you

Comment: Is your organization already using Active Directory?

Comment: In the organization, there is no actual Active Directory, I would have to built one from scratch. This idea came from my n+1 that worked with this once. But in this particular case, I wonder if it is not too big an infrastructure for one web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest benefit of using Windows Authentication in a website is if an organization is *already* using Active Directory, because it can enable seamless login. Your users wouldn't have to put in their credentials at all, and you already know who they are.

Setting up an Active Directory domain just for user management of one app is way overkill, for sure. For example, Lynda.com has a [2-hour course](https://www.lynda.com/Windows-Server-tutorials/Windows-Server-2016-Install-Configure-Active-Directory/520536-2.html) just about *installing* Active Directory.

Using something like OpenLDAP would be simpler, but still overkill in this scenario.

They're designed to manage, not just users, but computers, groups, policies, relationships to the external world...

If all you need is user and permission management for one application, then you're better off using something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helps. Could an argument to using Active Directory be "security" then? Does the LDAP protocol provide extra safety?

Comment: It wouldn't automatically improve security for your application, no. That would still depend on your application code.